# Using AJAX in django to delete a row in a table represented by a model

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I have a  representing a model and I want to be able to remove the row and delete the object from the DB without reloading the page.  On the left I have an X icon when clicked hides the row using .hide('slow') but how can I make it remove from the db?  Re-loading the page takes a while..  Can I delete the object using a form or using a /delete page?

Comment: You need to write a javascript ajax request that hits a route in your django app (/delete page).

Comment: Could you provide some sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jquery to easily make an ajax request

as part of the event handler that is triggered by a user clicking 'X', you can make a request to your django app.

```
$.post('/django/url/to/your/view', {idToDelete: 'value'}, function(response) {
  // callback
});
```

Of coures this is just on the client side.  In django you will need to creat a new urls.py entry and create the view logic to handle actually deleteing the id.

It is very important to include a csrf token in your post requests.  Django provides step by step on how to do this with ajax requests. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

Comment: remember CSRF https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax if you use POST.